# In meteor how to change ROOT_URL of development environment when developing over a LAN

Tags: meteor

I've got meteor on a linux box that I develop on through SSH to a windows laptop. For simple apps I can just substitute the lan address (10.0.1.101:3000) for localhost:3000 in the (windows)browser and it works.

But working through a tutorial that uses oauth w twitter, it seems meteor hardcodes ROOT_URL as localhost when in development environment and sends that to twitter.js. This happens even though in dev.twitter.com I have given the callback URL as

```
http://10.0.1.101:3000/_oauth/twitter?close.
```

Is there someway to develop on a machine that is not localhost?

Comment: you mean just setting ROOT_URL doesn't work when not using --production? That's hard to believe. Are you sure? What happens when you start it like this `ROOT_URL=http://10.0.1.101:3000 meteor`?

Comment: Thanks Christian, that seems to be working. On I go.

Comment: ok, great. I've added an answer just so the question doesn't appear unanswered (for future reference by others).

Answer (score 21):

You need to set the environment variable before starting meteor:

```
ROOT_URL=http://10.0.1.101:3000 meteor
```

Comment: It is possible to update the `process.env.ROOT_URL` at runtime ? (Before `packages/oauth/oauth_server.js` is called for socials services)

Comment: no, I don't think so. I seem to remember that I tried that at one point, too, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works hijacking the request and checking the request hostname, but it might not work for race conditions, as I don't know if this is process-safe:

```
WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use((req, res, next) => {
      var match: any
      if(
        req.url.startsWith('/_oauth/facebook') &&
        (match = req.headers.host.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.domain.com/))
      ) {
        Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl
          = process.env.ROOT_URL
          = match[0]
      }

      next()
    })
```

My problem was making the oauth work for multiple domains.